# How do I write/append to A CSV based on headers?

Tags: ruby, csv

I created a CSV file named `"file.csv"` that looks like this:

```
Artist,Album
```

I want to use Ruby's CSV library to write to it. But I want to write to the file using its header names. Something like this:

```
CSV.open("file.csv",'a'){|file|
  file["Artist"] = "foo"
  file["Album"] = "bar"
}
```

How do I do this with Ruby's CSV library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header = ["Artist","Album"]
CSV.open("file.csv","a") do |csv|
  row = CSV::Row.new(header,[])
  row["Artist"] = "foo"
  row["Album"] = "bar"
  csv << row
end
```